# Moving files that have no extensions in a number of directories into one directory

Tags: bash

I have a large collection of ~1,000 files (without extension, i.e. `1105`, `1106`,`5231`, etc.) spread across a corresponding number of folders. i.e. it is a thousand files like so:

`/users/me/collection/1105/1455`,`/users/me/collection/1106/1466`,`/users/me/collection/1110/1470`, etc. etc.

What I want to do is to find a quick way to move all these files in the sub directories (i.e. `1455`, `1466`, `1470`, etc.) into one single directory (i.e. `/users/me/collection-all/`).

To be honest, the lack of an extension is throwing me off, and I seem to keep `find`ing directories alongside the files... They are actually all PDFs, but w/o extension.

Comment: Is there anything in collection other than the directories with files you are talking about?

Comment: @Jasper No, it's just a directory of sub-directories, each with one file w/o an extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
mv /users/me/collection/*/* /users/me/collection-all/
```

Answer (score 4):

In fact the answer is very simple :

you can **find** them and exclude the directories :

```
cp ` find <your directory tree base> ! -type d` <your destination directory>
```

The "! -type d" will naturally exclude the results of type "directory".

HTH

Answer (score 1):

My two cents

```
cd /users/collections/me
find . -type f -exec mv {} /users/me/collection-all/ \;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS_BACKUP=$IFS
IFS=$'\n\t'

for i in $(find $source_directory -type f -iname "*" -print)
do
  mv -nv "$i" "$target_directory"
done

IFS=$IFS_BACKUP

exit
```

Just make sure to replace the variables `$source_directory` and `$target_directory` with the appropriate paths.